# Segmentation fault (core dumped) using boost::split in C++

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault

I have std::string wktString:

```
PROJCS["OSGB 1936 / British National Grid",GEOGCS["OSGB 1936",DATUM...
```

and trying to split this string

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
...
std::vector<std::string> proj_list;
boost::split(proj_list, wktString, boost::is_any_of("["));
std::cout << "split finish";
```

And when I compile I have a segmentation fault before "split finish".
Why?

Comment: There are three steps in running programs written in a compiled language_ 1 - Edit, 2 - Compile, 3 - Run. Your crash, the segmentation fault, is in the third step when *running* your program, not when compiling.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information. Please post a complete example (e.g., how wktString is initialized and where it's declared) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: @JoshKelley I initialize wktString previously reading from file and check it by std::cout. Problem isn't in wktString.

Comment: @koch_kir - There are a few possible causes of a crash like this. (1) Something corrupts wktString from the time you read it to the time you use it. (2) You're corrupting your heap somehow, and adding to proj_list triggers a segfault when it hits the corruption. (3) You're compiling and linking wrong (e.g., mixing ABI settings; very unlikely). (4) boost::split has a bug. #4 is _incredibly_ unlikely, and you _haven't given us enough information_ to help with #1-3.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely need more information.
This program compiles and runs w/o error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main ()
{
    std::string wktString = "PROJCS[\"OSGB 1936 / British National Grid\",GEOGCS[\"OSGB 1936\",DATUM...";
    std::vector<std::string> proj_list;
    boost::split(proj_list, wktString, boost::is_any_of("["));
    for ( int i = 0; i < proj_list.size(); ++i )
        std::cout << proj_list[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I know that this is not really an answer, but a comment was too small to show the complete program.